# preg_match_all problems

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i use preg_match_all and need to grab all a href="" tags in my code, but i not relly understand how to its work.

i have this reg. exp. ( /(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(</\2>)/ ) its take all html codes, i need only all a href tags.

i hobe i can get help :)

Comment: They will spear you for not using an XML parser...

Comment: (i) href is an attribute, not a tag; so do you also want to include `<link href=''>` tags? (ii) Use an XML parser!

Comment: Yeah, Regular expressions engines were not designed to be used on such simple tasks, use an XML parser!

Comment: Do you want the whole <a href='........'> tag? or just the contents of the href attribute for the tag?

Comment: This kind of question always gets the same answer: "use an XML parser!" However, I never actually see *code* for an XML parser solution... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of parsing HTML with RegExp, but anyway:

```
$input_string = file_get_contents(
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817449/preg-match-all-problems/2817549"
);

preg_match_all(
    '@\\<a\\b[^\\>]+\\bhref\\s*=\\s*"([^"]*)"[^\\>]*\\>@i',
    $input_string,
    $matches
);

var_dump( $matches ); // inspect for useful information
```

It expects that all hrefs are enclosed inside `"`. Won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$html = '<a href="http://something.com" target="_blank">Test </a>';
if (preg_match('/href="([^"]*)"/i', $html , $regs))
{
   $result = $regs[1];
} else {
   $result = "No URL Found";
}
echo $result ;
?>
```

Comment: firstly, <a> tags arent the only tags that can have href attributes (the <link> tag also has them).
secondly, this will also match href='soemthing' outside of < and >, in which case its not actually a tag.

Comment: Tanks but its aslo take ".css" urls and more... :) i need only <a href="(myurl)">(title)</a>

Comment: pass whatever you want to $html it does preg_match on $html